# Code Logic of when close the statement java

Tags: oracle, jdbc, database-connection, resultset

Well always teach me this way of open and close connections from database, then i search more and more because this is very important for the performance of my application.

Here is my Class connection

```
public class Connection {

jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxx;
protected static Connection cn = null;

protected Connection getCn() {
    return cn;
}

public static void setCn(Connection cn) {
    Connection.cn = cn;
}

public ResultSet select(String sql) throws Exception {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement st = null;
    try {
        st = this.getCn().createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return rs;
}

public void insert(String sql) throws Exception {
    Statement st = null;
    try {
        st = this.getCn().createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public Connection connect() throws Exception {        
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        setCn(DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, "user", "password"));
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return cn;
}
```

Well that was for my Connection Class, now here i have some others class that extends from my Connection class to bring me data from the DataBase.

```
public String checkMethod() throws Exception {
    ResultSet rs;
    String sql = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    try {
        this.connect();
        rs = this.select(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            //some data collect
        }
        rs.close();   //here is my dude because when may i can put the statement.close() line?         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        this.cerrar();
    }
    return "success";
}
```

im using jsf and oracle, i think this snippet should be in my class Connection after the catch but generates me and error of the resulset is closed when i execute the method rs.next() and is logic because the statement must be close after the reading data of the resultSet, so how can i close the statement in my class Connection or in other place??? any suggestions? please help me

```
finally {
        if (st != null) {
            st.close();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix to the problem is:

```
finally {
   try{ st.close(); }catch( Exception ex ) { /* do nothing*/ }
}
```

this prevents from throwing an error when something goes wrong with the statement in other places of the code ( st is null, st is closed etc.).

A more elegant solution might be creating a helper class with methods that close statements, resultsets etc. and hide exceptions that occur:

```
class DbCloser{
  static void closeQuietly( Statement st ){
     try{
       st.close();
     } catch( Exception ex ){
        /* do nothing */
     }
  }

  static void closeQuietly( ResultSet rs ){
     try{
       rs.close();
     } catch( Exception ex ){
        /* do nothing */
     }
  }
  // .... etc.
}
```

and then use that helper class in finally blocks in code:

```
finally {
   DbCloser.closeQuietly( st ); 
}
```

There is ready-made `DbUtils` package from Appache Commons that has already implemented such helper methods, just download this library and place it in the class-path, see this links for details: 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/index.html

And finally I would suggest to place `close` methods only in `finnaly` blocks:

```
  try {
       ......
        rs = this.select(sql);
       .......
       ...........
        // Do not close the statement here ......
        // rs.close();   //here is my dude because when may i can put the statement.close() line?         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        // ..... always close it here !!!
        DbUtils.closeQuietly( st );
        .........
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this one

```
finally {
   try{ 
     if(st!=null){
        st.close();
        st=null;
     }
   }catch( Exception ex ) 
   {
     /* you can log this*/ 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it like this:

```
public String checkMethod() throws Exception {
    ResultSet rs;
    String sql = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    try {
        this.connect();
        rs = this.select(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            //some data collect
        }
        rs.close(); 
        rs.getStatement().close(); 'This works for me =) 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        this.cerrar();
    }
    return "success";
}
```